# SWT TrayItem location

Tags: swt

I use SWT + JFace and want to show my application window near the tray icon, like ToolTip.

Is there a way to get the location of a TrayItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no platform-agnostic way to do this AFAIK. Ig you really need it, you'll likely need to code to the underlying SWT platform API as per your GTK example. One way I've done this which builds/runs everywhere is to use reflection to call the methods based on what SWT.getPlatform () returns.

If the window is mouse-triggered (e.g. by hover) you could consider using the mouse location as the base location for the hover.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this, but since `TrayItem` extends `Item`, which is an instance of `Widget`, why not try this:

```
Tray tray = display.getSystemTray();
TrayItem trayItem = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);
Rectangle bounds = trayItem.getDisplay().getBounds();
```

Comment: Hello, Paul.

Thank you for the answer! But I try it and it seems that for tray item it does't work. I found next solution (but it's platform dependent):

int itemHandle = trayItem.handle;
   
GdkRectangle areaRectangle = new GdkRectangle();
OS.gtk_status_icon_get_geometry(itemHandle, 0, areaRectangle, 0);
windowX = areaRectangle.x;
windowY = areaRectangle.y;

Best regards!
Alex