# How to get a SWT Tray or TrayItem location

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Any ideas how to get the location of the system tray (Tray) or item's on it (TrayItem) with SWT? Getting the bounds from the display only gives me the entire screen's bound. ie

```
item.getDisplay().getBounds();
```

will give me (0, 0, 1024, 1024) on my Windows box.

I'd also like to know if the system tray position (left, right, top, bottom) but can probably guess given the location. **This is all so I can popup a message near the system tray**.

This is a duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960930/swt-trayitem-location) but I want to offer a bounty (and so control what I consider a correct answer).

Comment: This would be really nice to implement GUI tests that also honor the tray.

Comment: Question: why didn't you start a bounty on the other post you mentioned?

Comment: it wouldn't let me! i figured I had to be the owner

Comment: really? I thought one could place a bounty on any question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who tried to answer. However, as with the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960930/swt-trayitem-location), I think its just not possible so I'm answering my own question in the negative :(

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display a shell near the tray item reacting to a user event (as is my case). You can get the pointer location when the event is triggered over the tray item:

```
trayItem.addSelectionListener (new SelectionListener () {
    @Override public void widgetDefaultSelected (SelectionEvent aEvent) {
        widgetSelected (aEvent);
    }

    @Override public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent aEvent) {
        if (mWindow.isVisible ()) {
            Shell wnd = mWindow;
            mWindow = new Shell (mDisplay);
            wnd.close ();
        }
        else {
            mWindow.setLocation (mDisplay.getCursorLocation ());
            mWindow.open ();
        }
    }
});
```

You can find the whole source code [here](https://github.com/jamming/passwordcard/blob/master/src/main/java/co/warizmi/passwordcard/App.java#L121).

If you want to notify some other event (not generated by user input), I guess your best bet is to use a ToolTip as Sandman points out in the previous answer.

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

`widget.getDisplay()` always returns the display used for the specified widget, so that will never work.

I far as I can see for both Win32 and MacOS, you will not get the location before the first mouse event on the item itself ;-(

If you are willing to add some architecture dependent code, you can try the following...

For MacOS - though not tested:

- sub-class `TrayItem` (remember to override `checkSubClass()`)
- use `getLocation()` to return the current location of the item

For Win32 - again not tested - you can try the same but this time override `messageProc(...)`. One of the first messages will allow you to query the current location of the handle...

Comment: thanks, i'll have a play. how about some way to record the location when I create the tray item and just associate with item addData(...) or similar? You think there's any options there?

Comment: You might be better off seeing if you can access the relevant information in a different way. E.g by looking in the registries... The solution above cannot be expected to work across major versions of SWT :-(

Comment: bummer. any pointers as to where I'd start with that suggestion? :S

Comment: Sorry no... I have absolutely no ideas :-(

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the API, it looks like there is no such option (in contrast with, e.g. a `ToolItem`). :(

Answer (score 0):

You can map from one coordinate system to another by using Display.map.  You can map your item's 0,0 (Upper Left) into Display coordinates by doing:

```
Display.map(item, null, 0, 0)
```

Use null as the "to" control for mapping to the Display coordinate space.

Comment: This does not work for TrayItem since it doesn't subclass Control.